# SQL Results in Rows not Columns

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am trying to list the results of my query in rows not columns. I have research Pivot Tables and numerous items and thought I would post my question here. This query is getting the list of deposits made for a restaurant chain. There could be 1 per day or up to 5. The manufactures software has them listed in the normal transactions and not numbered in any way.

Below is my query.

```
use SpeedlinkDB
SELECT 
  ad.StoreID,
  (ad.Amount * -1) as anAmount    
FROM AccountDetail ad
LEFT JOIN DayFileSummary DF ON ad.StoreId = DF.StoreID and ad.EODID = DF.EODID    
WHERE 
(DATEDIFF(d, df.DF_BusinessDay, GETDATE()) = 1)    
AND ( ad.TransType = 18 )
GROUP BY 
  ad.StoreID,
  ad.Amount    
ORDER BY ad.StoreID
```

Query Results....

```
StoreID    anAmount
1104       667.28
1104       110.00
1107       750.00
1107       211.00
1107       464.20
1205       280.11
etc..
```

What I would like is the following...

```
StoreID    Deposit1    Deposit2    Deposit3    Deposit4
1104       667.28      110.00  
1107       750.00      211.00      464.20
1205       280.11
```

The main reason being we use Reporting Services to display summary information for the management on the previous day. Among other information they want to see each deposit, sales, etc...

Thank you in advance for any help that can be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Rajesh Chamarthi's answer (+1), you can avoid the case statement and pivot if you use a Matrix Control:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Reporting+Services+%28SSRS%29/63415/

You'll still need to use Rajesh's ROW_NUMER() in order to split it out by deposit... but you can skip the case statements if using the Matrix Control...

```
SELECT 
    StoreID, 
    Deposit, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by StoreID) AS DepositNumber
from (<< Your Query above>>)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, at least almost. The link I will save as I am sure I will use that for many other things down the road. As far as the flaming above by Bohemian, it is on any message board. The numbering of the deposits works however it does them all combined. I am trying to get them to be number for each individual store as in the layout I have in the OP. Currently, it numbers 1-540. The DepositNumber would start 1,2,3 and then start over when it got to the next store.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the ROW_NUMBER function to assign sequential numbers for each StoreID and then use the ID and key to do the Pivot.

If you have some other parameter (for eg. deposit time) that you want to order the deposits by, you can add the order by in the partition by windowing clause.

Something like this.

```
select StoreID,
       max(case DepositNumber when 1 then Deposit else null end) Deposit1
       max(case DepositNumber when 2 then Deposit else null end) Deposit2
       max(case DepositNumber when 3 then Deposit else null end) Deposit3
       max(case DepositNumber when 4 then Deposit else null end) Deposit4
       max(case DepositNumber when 5 then Deposit else null end) Deposit5
  from (
            SELECT StoreID, 
                   Deposit, 
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by StoreID) AS DepositNumber
            from (<< Your Query above>> 
        )
   group by StoreID;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For SQL I would the same theory just with CASE instead of DECODE?

Comment: @Ken. you are correct. I come from an oracle background.. hence the decodes :). Updated my query above.

Comment: +1 for having enough sympathy to answer. I would have commented that this is a silly idea - what if there are 1000 deposits? Are we gonna code 1000 columns? Crazy.

Comment: The OP mentioned that there can be up to (maximum) 5 deposits a day. I seriously doubt if any user would like to see the cross tab report if there could be 1000 deposits a day. That would be crazy toooo. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both of you for your help. The second answer used less resources and was faster but appreciate the input. My mistake was replacing the partition with the order by due to an error I was receiving. Use them both and I get exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!

```
SELECT 
ad.StoreID, 
ad.Amount, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By ad.StoreID Order by ad.StoreID) AS DepositNumber
FROM AccountDetail ad
LEFT JOIN DayFileSummary DF ON ad.StoreId = DF.StoreID and ad.EODID = DF.EODID

WHERE 
(DATEDIFF(d, df.DF_BusinessDay, GETDATE()) = 1)

AND (ad.TransType = 18)
```